# Creating one row of information in excel using a unique value

Tags: excel, vba, uniqueidentifier, mergesort

This is my first post.  I am currently working on a project at work which requires that I work with several different worksheets in order to create one mail master worksheet, as it were, in order to do a mail merge. The worksheet contains information regarding different purchases, and each purchaser is identified with their own ID number. Below is an example of what my spreadsheet looks like now (however I do have more columns):

```
ID  Salutation     Address  ID      Name        Donation      ID  Name          Tickets
9   Mr. John Doe    123     12  Ms. Jane Smith   100.00       12  Ms.Jane Smith   300.00 
12  Ms. Jane Smith  456     22  Mr. Mike Man     500.00       84  Ms. Jo Smith    300.00
```

What I would like to do is somehow sort my data so that everythign with the same unique identifier (ID) lines up on the same row.  For example ID 12 Jane Smith - all the information for her will show up under her name matched by her ID number, and ID 22 will match up with 22 etc...

When I merged all of my spreadsheets together, I sorted them all by ID number, however my problem is, not everyone who made a donation bought a ticket or some people just bought tickets and nothing us, so sorting doesn't work.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Excel VBA. If you haven't used VBA in Excel before, see the link below to see how to access it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx

**Make sure you backup your spreadsheet before trying any of this in case something goes wrong!**

I wrote something up that will copy data from your secondary worksheets into your main worksheet. Just open the VBA editor, and paste in the code.

Next, edit the `ConsolidateWorksheets()` function so that it has the right names for your sheets. If you have additional sheets, declare them and add another line that calls the `ProcessWorksheet` subroutine for the added sheet.

This code will copy data from your tickets and donations worksheet into your main worksheet when it finds a matching id. If there isn't a matching id, it doesn't copy anything for that row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateWorksheets()

    'declare the worksheets you are using
    Dim mainWks As Worksheet
    Dim ticketsWks As Worksheet
    Dim donationsWks As Worksheet

    'set the worksheet names
    Set mainWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ticketsWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set donationsWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    Call ProcessWorksheet(mainWks, ticketsWks)
    Call ProcessWorksheet(mainWks, donationsWks)

End Sub

' copies data from the otherWks to the mainWks
Sub ProcessWorksheet(mainWks As Worksheet, otherWks As Worksheet)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowId As Integer

    Dim otherRowIndex As Integer
    Dim otherLastColIndex As Integer

    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer

    Dim pasteColStart As Integer
    Dim pasteColEnd As Integer

    ' figure out the last row in the main sheet
    lastRowIndex = mainWks.UsedRange.Rows.count
    otherLastColIndex = otherWks.UsedRange.Columns.count

    ' figure out where to copy and paste from
    ' this assumes that the id row is always the first row in every sheet
    pasteColStart = mainWks.UsedRange.Columns.count + 1
    pasteColEnd = pasteColStart + (otherLastColIndex - 2)

    ' copy column headers
    otherWks.Activate
    otherWks.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, otherLastColIndex)).Copy
    mainWks.Activate
    mainWks.Range(Cells(1, pasteColStart), Cells(1, pasteColEnd)).PasteSpecial

    ' loop through all the rows of the main sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRowIndex
        ' get row id from first cell in current row
        rowId = Cells(i, 1).Value
        'lookup row id in other worksheets
        otherRowIndex = FindIdRowInWks(otherWks, rowId)

        If otherRowIndex <> 0 Then
            otherWks.Activate
            otherWks.Range(Cells(otherRowIndex, 2), Cells(otherRowIndex, otherLastColIndex)).Copy
            mainWks.Activate
            mainWks.Range(Cells(i, pasteColStart), Cells(i, pasteColEnd)).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

' loops through the given worksheet, looks for a given id in the first column
' and returns the row index where the id was found. returns 0 if nothing found.
Public Function FindIdRowInWks(wks As Worksheet, idToFind As Integer) As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = wks.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rowNumber As Integer
    rowNumber = 0

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If (Cells(i, 1).Value = idToFind) Then
            rowNumber = i
        End If
    Next i
    FindIdRowInWks = rowNumber
End Function
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 Steps without VBA:

1) Create new worksheet

2) On New Sheet get a consolidated list of ID & Salutation

For XL2007 see Remove Duplicates, for XL2003 see advanced filter.

3) Create a Setup Like so using vlookups and iferror to grab the values you want based on the relevant sections from the original sheet. See the image and the vlookup formula in the formula bar

[image]